# Jenkins or Chef

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, chef-infra, devops

I'm coming from Microsoft Team Foundation Server. In open source world there I found two famous CI servers i.e. Jenkins and Chef. I'm wondering which one to start first so that I can proceed with other.

Can someone please guide which one is more easy to understand and let me start with open source world tools?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Chef is a configuration management tool. Not a CI system. Unless you mean Chef Automate's CD component (Workflow), which is a relatively niche tool.

Comment: Oh, the way both of their names are taken when discussing about Open Source CI things, I thought both may be dealing with CI things...